# Как сделать чтобы скрипт срабатывал только если есть определенный тег с классом на странице

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы скрипт срабатывал только если есть определенный тег с классом на странице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($("div").is("selector")){}
```

смотрите [здесь](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) детальней

Comment: Спасибо, Алекс!

Comment: @ВикторВиктор а к спасибо можно +1 ответу

Answer (score 2):

Если без `jQuery`, то можно использовать [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
if (document.querySelectorAll("div.example").length) {
  // содержимое скрипта
}
```

C `jQuery`:

```
if ($("div.example").length) {
  // содержимое скрипта
}
```